# InvalidForeignKey Apartment Gem when creating records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apartment-gem

I have excluded user model in apartment initializer file.

```
config.excluded_models = %w{Franchise User Franchiser}
```

I have a ternary model between project and user but when i add members it throughs beneath error.

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey (PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "members" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_2e88fb7ce9"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(6) is not present in table "users".
: INSERT INTO "members" ("user_id", "project_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "email") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"):
```

Any help will be apperciated.

Comment: You are trying to create a new `Member` and save it _before_ the respective `User` was saved. Without seeing your code we can’t tell you more.

Comment: The User is already saved in the public schema and i want to use that.

Comment: **Without seeing your code we can’t tell you more.**

Comment: Have you worked with apartment gem boss ?

Comment: If a new project is created, it will trigger to create a new member with the corresponding user. Project are beginning created with the same user, no issue it picks the user from the public schema. But when we create member it gives above error.

after_create :add_creator_as_member

def add_creator_as_member
      self.users << self.user
end

Comment: After alot of head banging I wounded up removing,  
    remove_foreign_key :members , :users
I know this is not correct but for now it's working.